# Aggregating by group in R data.table when column is non-numeric

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set that looks like:

```
id | X | Y
1  | 5 | a
1  | 6 | a
1  | 9 | a
2  | 2 | f
2  | 6 | f
```

Column `Y` is a string or factor that is the same within a group `id`. In `data.table`, I am trying to aggregate by group and get out some statistics, for example the mean of `X` by `id`. I would also like to get `Y`. The end result would be

```
id | X    | Y
1  | 6.66 | a
2  | 4    | f
```

The way I do this in `data.table` if there are not factor/string variables is `dt[,.(X = mean(X)), by = .(id)]`. If `Y` was a numeric variable that was the same within a group, I could use `max, min, mean` as well.

How do I get, for example, the first observation of each group? I know I can do two separate commands, one for all numeric variables and one for only strings/factors getting their first observations by group, then merging. But I would like to know if there is a way to do it in a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `first` function in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, .(X = mean(X), Y = first(Y)), by = .(id)]
```

or may simply use indexing `[1]`

```
dt[, .(X = mean(X, na.rm = TRUE), Y = Y[1]), by = .(id)]
```

---

Based on the data showed, the 'Y' value can also be used in grouping

```
dt[, .(X = mean(X, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(id, Y)]
```

---

If there are more than one `numeric`/`character/factor` columns, use an `if/else` condition

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) 
            mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) else first(x)), by = .(id)]
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE),
           across(where(~ is.character(.)|| is.factor(.)), first))
```